# Resharper shortcuts jumbled

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

Yes, I have gone to "Manage options" and reset all settings.

When I press ctrl+shift+T, Resharper swaps the selected word with the one on the right. But the way I'm used to, and what I think is standard, is that this shortcut prompts a file search.

Similarly, shift+alt+T swaps lines vertically, and ctrl+T swaps two adjacent characters.

Why is this and what is the cure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're still using the default [Visual Studio shortcuts](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/) rather than the ReSharper ones.

I believe you'll need to go to ReSharper | Options | Environment - Keyboard & Menus and select your [preferred scheme](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html) (Visual Studio in this case) and ensure that you press "Apply Scheme" - this should update your Visual Studio defaults.

Note that on that options page it states:

> Note: applying a new keyboard scheme does not cancel any keybindings set by the previous scheme. To start from scratch [...] reset the the keyboard bindings to their defaults at Visual Studio Options, Environment | Keyboard page.

Comment: That was it. Visual Studio was selected, but hitting 'apply' did the trick. Wohoo.